# The famous old issue of LINQ to Entities queries with filter on nullable fields

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I use EF6 in combination with LINQ.

Long time ago I met the famous issue of LINQ to Entities queries with filter on nullable fields, in particoular queries that compare nullable fields with not-nullable values. But now the issue is blocking me in my work, then it force me to use t-SQL in the place of LINQ.

I try to explain the issue better with the example:

this is my LINQ query:

```
Dim q = db.myTable1.Where(Function(a) db.myTable2.Any(Function(b) If(b.myInt1 = a.myNullableInt1 AndAlso b.myInt2 = a.myNullableInt2, True, False)) = False)
```

I use a 'ternary If' inside the 'Any' clause, because otherwise I get the error "impossible to convert Boolean? to Boolean"

this is the generated t-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Extent1.myNullableInt1 AS myNullableInt1, 
    Extent1.myNullableInt2 AS myNullableInt2, 
    ...
    FROM myTable1 AS Extent1
    WHERE 0 = (CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS C1
        FROM myTable2 AS Extent2
        WHERE (CASE WHEN (((CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ((Extent2.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) OR ((Extent2.myInt1 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent2.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent2.myInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ((Extent2.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) OR ((Extent2.myInt1 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent2.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent2.myInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1) AND ((CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ((Extent2.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) OR ((Extent2.myInt2 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent2.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent2.myInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ((Extent2.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) OR ((Extent2.myInt2 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent2.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent2.myInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1)) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 1
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS C1
        FROM myTable2 AS Extent3
        WHERE (CASE WHEN (((CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ((Extent3.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) OR ((Extent3.myInt1 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent3.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent3.myInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ((Extent3.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) OR ((Extent3.myInt1 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent3.myInt1 = Extent1.myNullableInt1) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent3.myInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1) AND ((CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ((Extent3.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) OR ((Extent3.myInt2 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent3.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent3.myInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ((Extent3.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) OR ((Extent3.myInt2 IS NULL) AND (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((Extent3.myInt2 = Extent1.myNullableInt2) AND ((CASE WHEN (Extent3.myInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (Extent1.myNullableInt2 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1)) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 1
    )) THEN cast(0 as bit) END)
```

As you can see it's quite 'abstruse', expecially considering that I can obtain the same result with this query t-SQL, very more 'clean':

```
SELECT a.*
FROM myTable1 a

WHERE a.myNullableInt1 IS NOT NULL
AND a.myNullableInt2 IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT b.*
    FROM myTable2 b

    WHERE b.myInt1 = a.myNullableInt1
    AND b.myInt2 = a.myNullableInt2
)
```

But this is not the issue: the LINQ query takes about 1 minute to be executed, the query t-SQL is immediate.
As I have said, I'm forced to use t-SQL in the place of LINQ.

```
Dim q = DirectCast(db, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of myTable1)(stringaSQL)
```

Have you got a better solution?
Why, in this case, EF is so inefficient?

Thank you!
Erminio

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the LINQ Query is slower because the entire object is queried.

EF regards your query as `IEnumerable` and not `IQueryable`.

Therefore it first queries all the fields of `a` from Table1 and then queries all the fields of `b` from Table2.
The casting from the nullable to non nullable type is done in memory, which is expensive.

In the SQL query, the DB handles that logic for you.

The first thing I would do is to replace the Nullable Integer
with a regular `int` and set one of its values as invalid, for example `Integer.MinValue`.

This way, the entire query would stay `IQueryable` and would be run in the DB.